# zipfile.badzipfile even when I'm not reading zip file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In the current path there are multiple folders, each folder has multiple folders or xlsx files inside,I want to iterate through each folder and read the xlsx files until there are no more folders or until all xlsx files are read. There are 50+ folders and 2000+ excel files. Below is my code:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

current_path=os.getcwd()
dfs = []

def process_folder(path):
    for item in os.listdir(path):
        item_path=os.path.join(path, item)

        if os.path.isdir(item_path):
            process_folder(item_path)
        
        elif item.endswith('.xlsx'):
            df = pd.read_excel(item_path)
            dfs.append(df)

process_folder(current_path)
result_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
result_df.to_excel('result.xlsx')
```

when I run the code, it shows error:"Excel file cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually". So I modified read_excel: `df = pd.read_excel(item_path, engine='openpyxl')`.
Then there is the error: "zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file."
However, I didn't read any zipfile. Not sure why this error shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have files with the extension `.xlsx` but which are not real Excel files. To find them, you can use:

```
import pathlib

for filename in pathlib.Path.cwd().glob('*.xlsx'):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as xlsx:
        sig = xlsx.read(2)
        if sig != b'PK':
            print(f'"{filename}" does not appear to be a valid Excel file')
```

Testing the signature of a `zip` file with `.xlsx` extension should be sufficient for the moment.

Comment: Thank you so much! The binary method works.

Answer (score 1):

That error happens because a `XLSX` file is, essentially, a zipfile with a bunch of XML files inside it.

I would recommend looking which of the `XLSX` files are causing the error, then checking if the affected ones don't happen to be just renamed `XLS` files; open those on Excel, them use `Save as...` to save them as proper `XLSX` files.